# Is it that bad to use Homebrew on an outdated macOS?

Tags: mac, homebrew, neovim

I had problems on macOS Monterey and had to downgrade back to Catalina due to performance issues (found out it was just my MBP 2016 needing some hardware cleaning, so I'm considering going back to Monterey). **Now I can't install neovim or vim.**

On Catalina I tried to `brew install nvim` and got stuck, as it asked me to install xCode (the Command Line Tools wouldn't be enough), which is a 10gb install. That's a bummer, so let's go back to my good old Vim. To get the updated version I went `brew install vim` but got stuck again when trying to install rust as a dependency: it took forever, made the mbp fans spin like crazy and nothing. I even installed rust and then `brew install vim --ignore-dependencies rust` and got several errors.

I finally got Neovim installed by following the instructions on its website, but I really wanted to keep using Homebrew.

Is that what they are trying to warn here?

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from MacHomebrew on Twitter.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.
```

The only reason I'm afraid of updating to Monterey is due to performance issues with OBS, which I use to manage my online piano lessons. My MBP should be able to handle it, right? Will I be having the same issues if I update macOS?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceU5V.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s possible Homebrew no longer has the pre-built packages for Catalina available online, so you’ll have to build them all, required extensive dependencies and time.

Comment: Your machine has plenty of CPU and RAM for OBS and that latest macOS version that still supported your 2016 MBP. Apple's pretty careful to keep OS updates from slowing down legacy hardware significantly. It's best to just always stay up to date (you don't have to be the very first person to update to the new major OS each fall, but by winter once the ".2" release is out, it's time to update. Trying to keep unsupported obsolete releases running well requires a lot of sysadmin knowledge, experience, and time, as Homebrew tried to warn you.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Homebrew installation instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) current version requires Big Sur or higher. El Capitan - Catalina are unsupported but may work; anything older doesn't work.